# Import of keystore into artifactory does not show any aliases available

Tags: keystore, artifactory

I'm currently evaluating the jar signing feature of the Artifactory Pro version. I'm following the manual found here: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/WebStart+and+Jar+Signing. Creating a keystore file with two keys was successful. This is what the `-list` command returns:

```
Keystore-Typ: JKS
Keystore-Provider: SUN

Keystore enthält 2 Einträge

Aliasname: publicuploadb
Erstellungsdatum: 16.12.2016
Eintragstyp: PrivateKeyEntry
Zertifikatskettenlänge: 1
Zertifikat[1]:
Eigentümer: CN=projektB, OU=Dev, O=Accso, ST=NRW, C=DE
Aussteller: CN=projektB, OU=Dev, O=Accso, ST=NRW, C=DE
Seriennummer: 511a6be7
Gültig von: Fri Dec 16 11:49:01 CET 2016 bis: Fri Jul 17 12:49:01 CEST 2026
Zertifikat-Fingerprints:
     MD5:  42:0A:9F:07:6B:42:A5:60:AA:E3:48:56:96:AC:DA:99
     SHA1: A5:98:E0:E2:DC:9C:1E:96:72:C0:D5:D4:32:37:4D:F2:E0:DE:CB:54
     SHA256: FA:03:39:C6:8F:7F:AB:FA:D7:98:DD:E4:4D:9E:28:19:AF:D2:C1:53:95:FA:FC:3E:F6:28:FF:09:7B:B4:83:7A
     Signaturalgorithmusname: SHA1withDSA
     Version: 3

Erweiterungen: 

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: FB 75 5E D2 02 70 8C 1F   22 55 ED FE BA 3B 44 B2  .u^..p.."U...;D.
0010: 8B 5B 1F 41                                        .[.A
]
]



*******************************************
*******************************************


Aliasname: publicuploada
Erstellungsdatum: 16.12.2016
Eintragstyp: PrivateKeyEntry
Zertifikatskettenlänge: 1
Zertifikat[1]:
Eigentümer: CN=projektA, OU=Dev, O=Accso, ST=NRW, C=DE
Aussteller: CN=projektA, OU=Dev, O=Accso, ST=NRW, C=DE
Seriennummer: 52ce08b0
Gültig von: Fri Dec 16 11:49:01 CET 2016 bis: Fri Jul 17 12:49:01 CEST 2026
Zertifikat-Fingerprints:
     MD5:  58:2F:F7:D3:18:25:6A:53:78:FC:97:84:DE:DC:B1:A6
     SHA1: 72:53:B9:5C:F6:E1:B1:53:7B:7D:D7:04:52:F2:E3:5A:A7:AA:85:E4
     SHA256: 9A:11:65:D4:D1:4D:21:1B:00:FB:34:7D:B0:33:A5:DA:F8:5D:8E:AF:70:EB:EF:46:D3:78:3E:E6:46:83:F2:28
     Signaturalgorithmusname: SHA1withDSA
     Version: 3

Erweiterungen: 

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 2B 13 10 16 5B 05 13 AB   F5 1D 1B CD 88 5F 40 EB  +...[........_@.
0010: 25 B7 A7 56                                        %..V
]
]
```

I could also succuessfully set a keystore password and upload the keystore file. However, this is when the trouble starts. The first thing which is a little confusing is that the GUI keeps complaining about the keystore password field being empty although I'm not trying to upload another file.

[image: error message]

But this is only a little annoying. The real trouble is that the two aliases ("publicuploada" and "publicuploadb") defined in the keystore are apparently not found since the alias pulldown menu only shows the generic entry "keystore"

[image]

When I try to set the alias name manually and klick "Save Keypair" I get the message "Alias doesn't exist in keystore".

I checked all logs files. There are no entries regarding the keystore to be found.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this is actually a known issue. See this [JIRA Ticket](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-8944).

There is a suggested workaround: make the filename of the keystore match the alias which is to be imported. I tested this solution by renaming my keystore to `publicuploada.data`. It worked.

Please, if you are affected, consider voting for fixing this issue in the JIRA ticket!